# Python: Pearson correlation coefficient and p-value between two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have two arrays with *x* columns and *y* rows, for which I would like to calculate the Pearson correlation coefficient and respective p-value.

Unfortunately,`scipy.stats.pearsonr` does not support 2-D inputs.

Is there a way to compute both the coefficient and the p-value between the two arrays?

Example arrays:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([[1,3,2], [5,6,4]])
array2 = np.array([[2,4,6], [10,8,6]])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Flatten both arrays won't give you the expected result?

Comment: AFAIK, Pearson is a correlation algorithm working on 1D data only and It is not mathematically defined for 2D arrays. What do you exactly want to do with your 2D array ? Is the 2D structure actually important ?

Comment: Check out NumPy's [`corrcoef`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html#numpy-corrcoef) function.